# Enumerating via interface - performance loss

Tags: c#, performance, list, ienumerable

I had a little  dispute (which was very close to holy war:) ) with my colleage, about the performance of access to list via indeces **VS** via enumerator. To operate with some facts, I wrote the following test:

```
   static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        const int count = 10000000;

        var stopwatch = new Stopwatch();

        var list = new List<int>(count);

        var rnd = new Random();

        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            list.Add( rnd.Next());
        }

        const int repeat = 20;

        double indeces = 0;
        double forEach = 0;

        for (int iteration = 0; iteration < repeat; iteration++)
        {
            stopwatch.Restart();
            long tmp = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
            {                    
                tmp += list[i];
            }

            indeces += stopwatch.Elapsed.TotalSeconds;
            stopwatch.Restart();
            foreach (var integer in list)
            {            
                tmp += integer;
            }

            forEach += stopwatch.Elapsed.TotalSeconds;
        }

        Console.WriteLine(indeces /repeat);
        Console.WriteLine(forEach /repeat);

    }
```

Actually, it just accesses the elements.

As I expected, index access was faster. This are the results of Release build on my machine:

```
    0.0347//index access
    0.0737//enumerating
```

However, I decided to change test a little:

```
        //the same as before
        ...
        IEnumerable<int> listAsEnumerable = list;
        //the same as before
        ...
        foreach (var integer in listAsEnumerable)
        {                
            tmp += integer;
        }
        ...
```

And now output was following:

```
    0.0321//index access
    0.1246//enumerating (2x slower!)
```

If we are enumerating the same list via interface, the performance is  **2 times** slower!

### Why does this* happening?

**this** means "enumerating via interface 2 times slower than enumerating the actual list".

My guess is that runtime is using different `Enumerator`s: the list's in first test and a generic one in the second test.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

When using `List<T>`, the `foreach` doesn't actually use the `IEnumerable<T>` interface; rather, it uses `List<T>.Enumerator`, which is a `struct`. At the trivial level, this means slightly less indirection - not having to de-reference, and using static calls rather than virtual calls - and a more direct implementation.

These differences are very very small, and in any sensible real-life example the difference is noise. However, it may be marginally noticeable if testing **just** the `foreach` performance.

To expand on this: `foreach` doesn't actually require `IEnumerable[<T>]` - it can work **purely** on the `GetEnumerator()` / `.MoveNext()` / `.Current` / `.Dispose()` pattern; this was especially important before generics in 2.0.

However, this is only possible when the variable is typed as `List<T>` (which has a custom `GetEnumerator()` method). Once you have `IEnumerable<T>`, it has to use `IEnumerator<T>`

Comment: Great answer! I actually looked at disassembled code of two versions, and noticed, that diffent enumerators were used. But my knowledge of 'il' is quite poor, so I decided to ask here:)

Answer (score 4):

You can see the code here:

```
static void Main()
{

    List<int> list = new List<int>(Enumerable.Range(1,10000));

    int total = 0;
    foreach (var i in list)
    {
        total += i;
    }
    IEnumerable<int> enumerable = list;
    foreach (var i in enumerable)
    {
        total += i;
    }
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Which generates this IL. Notice the difference between

```
System.Collections.Generic.List`1/Enumerator<int32>
```

and

```
System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1<int32>
```

and note that it is a `ValueType` (struct):

```
.method private hidebysig static void  Main() cil managed
{
  .entrypoint
  // Code size       146 (0x92)
  .maxstack  2
  .locals init ([0] class [mscorlib]System.Collections.Generic.List`1<int32> list,
           [1] int32 total,
           [2] int32 i,
           [3] class [mscorlib]System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1<int32> enumerable,
           [4] valuetype [mscorlib]System.Collections.Generic.List`1/Enumerator<int32> CS$5$0000,
           [5] bool CS$4$0001,
           [6] class [mscorlib]System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerator`1<int32> CS$5$0002)
  IL_0000:  nop
  IL_0001:  ldc.i4.1
  IL_0002:  ldc.i4     0x2710
  IL_0007:  call       class [mscorlib]System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1<int32> [System.Core]System.Linq.Enumerable::Range(int32,
                                                                                                                                  int32)
  IL_000c:  newobj     instance void class [mscorlib]System.Collections.Generic.List`1<int32>::.ctor(class [mscorlib]System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1<!0>)
  IL_0011:  stloc.0
  IL_0012:  ldc.i4.0
  IL_0013:  stloc.1
  IL_0014:  nop
  IL_0015:  ldloc.0
  IL_0016:  callvirt   instance valuetype [mscorlib]System.Collections.Generic.List`1/Enumerator<!0> class [mscorlib]System.Collections.Generic.List`1<int32>::GetEnumerator()
  IL_001b:  stloc.s    CS$5$0000
  .try
  {
    IL_001d:  br.s       IL_002d
    IL_001f:  ldloca.s   CS$5$0000
    IL_0021:  call       instance !0 valuetype [mscorlib]System.Collections.Generic.List`1/Enumerator<int32>::get_Current()
    IL_0026:  stloc.2
    IL_0027:  nop
    IL_0028:  ldloc.1
    IL_0029:  ldloc.2
    IL_002a:  add
    IL_002b:  stloc.1
    IL_002c:  nop
    IL_002d:  ldloca.s   CS$5$0000
    IL_002f:  call       instance bool valuetype [mscorlib]System.Collections.Generic.List`1/Enumerator<int32>::MoveNext()
    IL_0034:  stloc.s    CS$4$0001
    IL_0036:  ldloc.s    CS$4$0001
    IL_0038:  brtrue.s   IL_001f
    IL_003a:  leave.s    IL_004b
  }  // end .try
  finally
  {
    IL_003c:  ldloca.s   CS$5$0000
    IL_003e:  constrained. valuetype [mscorlib]System.Collections.Generic.List`1/Enumerator<int32>
    IL_0044:  callvirt   instance void [mscorlib]System.IDisposable::Dispose()
    IL_0049:  nop
    IL_004a:  endfinally
  }  // end handler
  IL_004b:  nop
  IL_004c:  ldloc.0
  IL_004d:  stloc.3
  IL_004e:  nop
  IL_004f:  ldloc.3
  IL_0050:  callvirt   instance class [mscorlib]System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerator`1<!0> class [mscorlib]System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1<int32>::GetEnumerator()
  IL_0055:  stloc.s    CS$5$0002
  .try
  {
    IL_0057:  br.s       IL_0067
    IL_0059:  ldloc.s    CS$5$0002
    IL_005b:  callvirt   instance !0 class [mscorlib]System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerator`1<int32>::get_Current()
    IL_0060:  stloc.2
    IL_0061:  nop
    IL_0062:  ldloc.1
    IL_0063:  ldloc.2
    IL_0064:  add
    IL_0065:  stloc.1
    IL_0066:  nop
    IL_0067:  ldloc.s    CS$5$0002
    IL_0069:  callvirt   instance bool [mscorlib]System.Collections.IEnumerator::MoveNext()
    IL_006e:  stloc.s    CS$4$0001
    IL_0070:  ldloc.s    CS$4$0001
    IL_0072:  brtrue.s   IL_0059
    IL_0074:  leave.s    IL_008a
  }  // end .try
  finally
  {
    IL_0076:  ldloc.s    CS$5$0002
    IL_0078:  ldnull
    IL_0079:  ceq
    IL_007b:  stloc.s    CS$4$0001
    IL_007d:  ldloc.s    CS$4$0001
    IL_007f:  brtrue.s   IL_0089
    IL_0081:  ldloc.s    CS$5$0002
    IL_0083:  callvirt   instance void [mscorlib]System.IDisposable::Dispose()
    IL_0088:  nop
    IL_0089:  endfinally
  }  // end handler
  IL_008a:  nop
  IL_008b:  call       string [mscorlib]System.Console::ReadLine()
  IL_0090:  pop
  IL_0091:  ret
} // end of method Program2::Main
```

Answer (score 2):

If you look at the IL for both versions, you will see that the first version uses an iterator of type `System.Collections.Generic.List<System.Int32>+Enumerator` -- a nested `struct`, which is optimized for iterating over a list.

The second version uses a generic implementation of `System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerator<System.Int32>`, which is less efficient because it does not "cheat" by keeping a private index to the current item in the list.

Comment: This is not quite right: the Enumerator is the **same**, but in the second case some overhead takes place because of accessing boxed Enumerator in heap(dereferencing) and virtual calls(`callvirt` vs `call` in il)

Answer (score 1):

I suspect there is a performance gain in employing for instead of foreach (at least for primitive types). As far as I know they are nearly equivalent if you perform for and foreach over the same array (not any other structure like lists, this creates some overheads by itself).

The performance of foreach and for depends on which type of structure you are running for and foreach.

Please check;
[For and Foreach comparison](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kevin_ransom/archive/2004/04/19/116072.aspx)